# Php 7 performances problems / script slow to unload?

Tags: apache, performance, centos7, php-7

Using PHP 7.0.11 (With Apache on a Centos 7 box), my scripts seams to be very slow to UNload.

This is very strange. My browser can takes up to 10 or 15 seconds to display a simple page. With PHP 5.6, it was ultra fast (some milliseconds).

After some tests, I noticed that more units I include in my script, slower it is to get the response from the server. But, what is strange is that the performance issue is not when the units are included into my script. Instead, the issue seams to be when PHP unload them.

As a test (see my sample code below), if I include 64 php files into my script it can takes up to 10 seconds to display the web page into my browser. However, at the end of my script, if I uncomment the line die("stop"); then is such case, the page is displayed as fast as it was with PHP 5.6.

```
<?php
 include_once 'unit1.php';
 include_once 'unit2.php';
 ...
 include_once 'unit64.php';

 echo "test";
 //die("stop");

?>
```

So, can somebody help me to find what is wrong with my configuration ?

Note that I tried to enable as well as disable opcache and it did not change anything. So, it does not seam to be related to opcache.

Comment: Try running your code using cli instead of apache, see it the problem persists. Also running it through strace could shed some light on where it hangs.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the problem myself. I had some problems with xdebug (it is now working fine) and I added the follwing line by mistake into the xdebug section of my php.ini file:

```
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
```

So, I just removed that line and now everything is working fast.